# Powershell - Create a progress bar for excel

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a progress bar for when I create an `XLSX` spreadsheet. I can't workout how to get it to work.

Below is my code.

*Updated my Code, this is the issue I am having, I added the whole code previously to show the function of Ex, but it seems that it is not needed. So custom created progess bar that I want to display to the user once it executes the Ex function, the function creates and updates an excel spreadsheet, I would like it to update the user in realtime as to the progress of each stage in Ex, it follows the following process;

- Creates Excel spreadsheet.
- Copies data from text file 1 - creates worksheet1
- Copies data from text file 2 - creates worksheet2
- Copies data from text file 3 - creates worksheet3
- Copies data from text file 4 - creates worksheet4
- Copies data from text file 5 - creates worksheet5
- Formats each worksheet
- Re-arranges the worksheets into the correct order of which they have been copied.
- Finally saves the spreadsheet and closes.

  Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

  ```
  ## -- Create The Progress-Bar
  $ObjForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $ObjForm.Text = "Finishing Process"
  $ObjForm.Height = 100
  $ObjForm.Width = 500
  $ObjForm.BackColor = "White"

  $ObjForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
  $ObjForm.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

  ## -- Create The Label
  $ObjLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
  $ObjLabel.Left = 5
  $ObjLabel.Top = 10
  $ObjLabel.Width = 500 - 20
  $ObjLabel.Height = 15
  $ObjLabel.Font = "Tahoma"
  ## -- Add the label to the Form
  $ObjForm.Controls.Add($ObjLabel)

  $PB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
  $PB.Name = "PowerShellProgressBar"
  $PB.Value = 0
  $PB.Style="Continuous"

  $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
  $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500 - 40
  $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
  $PB.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
  $PB.Left = 5
  $PB.Top = 40
  $ObjForm.Controls.Add($PB)

  ## -- Show the Progress-Bar and Start The PowerShell Script
  $ObjForm.Show() | Out-Null
  $ObjForm.Focus() | Out-NUll
  $ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
  $ObjForm.Refresh()

  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  Out-Null
  ## -- Execute The PowerShell Code and Update the Status of the Progress-Bar

  $Ex = Ex
  $Ex
  $Counter = 0
  ForEach ($Item In $Ex) {
      ## -- Calculate The Percentage Completed
      $Counter++
      [Int]$Percentage = ($Counter/$Ex.Count)*100
      $PB.Value = $Percentage
      $ObjLabel.Text = "Creating an Xlsx File Please wait"
      #$ObjLabel.Text = "Found $counter $Criteria in $Search"
      $ObjForm.Refresh()
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 150
      # -- $Item.Name
      #"`t" + $Item.Path

  }
  $ObjForm.Close()
  ```

Comment: there's built-in progress bar ability in powershell 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script/

Comment: The issue I get is that once I try to run it, it does not update as it cycles through the function Ex - this contains the excel write. I want it to update the progess bar once it has calulated how many steps it has to take and when each one has completed;

for example; once it has created the spreadsheet update the progress bar, once it has copied the data from text file one update the progress bar, so that the user gets realtime information and it constanly updates until the function is complete.